# How can I configure the serial port under debian 8.3 on HP Server?

Tags: linux, debian

If there is no Monitor I can access via the serial RS-232 port on Debian/GNU/Linux 8.3!

How can I configure the serial port under Debian 8.3. It should be possible already during the boot from Debian 8.3 so I can connect my Laptop to the RS232 interface of the server?

Debian Laptop connect to HP Server with minicom -b 38400 ( pu port /dev/ttyUSB0) to --> HP Server (Debian 8.3) with RS232 port

Thank you in advance

Vim

Answer (score 0):

Configuration:

Configure console access on the target machine:

GRUB2 and systemd

If you configure the serial console in GRUB2 systemd will create a getty listener on the same serial device as GRUB2 by default.

So, this is the only configuration needed for
Debian running with systemd. To make grub enable the serial console, open

## vi /etc/default/grub

Change the GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT line to start the console on /dev/ttyS0. Note in the example below, we set two consoles up; one on tty0 and one on the serial port.

## GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,38400n8"

Rebuild the grub.cfg file with following command:

## grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

After a reboot, getty will be listening on /dev/ttyS0, expecting 38400 baud, 8 data bits, no parity and one stop bit. When Debian 8.3 boots, systemd will automatically start a getty session to listen on the same device with the same settings.